# vue сборка отдельно от laravel

Tags: веб-программирование, laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel5

Здравствуйте, хочу отдельно поставить vue webpack сборку через vue-cli, чтобы не использовать дефолтную в laravel, laravel будет только как API. Сделал два проекта, laravel стоит на сервере xampp, vue на webpack dev server как я понял, не уверен что так правильно, чтобы сделать API пришлось еще разобраться с CORS(разрешил всем доменам). Как правильно сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста. Может xampp сейчас плох в современной разработке? Какой сервер выбрать если у меня виндовс? Как поставить такое на хостинг? Как в современней разработке правильнее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если кому интересно как захостить vue spa(созданное через `vue-cli`, то есть проекты разделены) на одном хостинге вместе с laravel, то [вот решение от разработчика Vue](https://github.com/iliyaZelenko/laravel-vue-cli-3).

Суть в том что для production build индексный файл генерируется как `resources/views/index.blade.php`, а статический ресурсы(js, css, img и т.д.) закидываеются в public папку laravel. Это очень удобный вариант для spa вместе с laravel, все можно закинуть на один хостинг, работает hot reload и отлично работает API, нет проблем с CORS(разные домены).

[Вот](https://github.com/iliyaZelenko/laravel5.7-vue-cli3-boilerplate) делал авторизацию на Vue cli 3 + Laravel 5.7.

[Вот](https://github.com/iliyaZelenko/vue-cli-laravel-todo) делал маленькое TODO приложение.

Если использовать Nuxt, то там довольно тяжело сделать spa с laravel на одном хостинге, [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848412/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-vue-nuxt-spa-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-laravel-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5) как я делал это через один пакет. Nuxt SSR + Laravel никак не захостишь вместе, SSR работает через nodejs сервер и нужно будет делать запрос с одного домена(клиент) на другой(сервер API).

Answer (score 1):

Правильно настроить все аспекты приложения с рендерингом на стороне сервера и готовое к развёртыванию на production может быть сложной задачей. К счастью, есть отличный проект сообщества, который стремится сделать всё проще: **Nuxt.js**.

> **Nuxt.js** — это высокоуровневый фреймворк, построенный на экосистеме
>   Vue, что обеспечит быстрое получение опыта разработки универсальных
>   приложений на Vue. И даже лучше, вы можете использовать его в качестве
>   генератора статических сайтов (со страницами представленными
>   однофайловыми компонентами)!

[ссыль на Nuxt.js](https://ru.nuxtjs.org/)