# Как захостить vue nuxt spa вместе с laravel вместе на одном хостинге и домене?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

делаю фронтенд на vue + nuxt(spa) и api через laravel. Подскажите как мне залить сгенерированное spa от nuxt вместе с laravel на один хостинг, чтобы был одинаковый домен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать два связаных удобных пакета: https://github.com/skyrpex/laravel-nuxt и https://github.com/skyrpex/laravel-nuxt-js
Они позволяют удобно разрабатывать spa, потом делать build в public/_nuxt откуда это будет отображаться на продакшене

Также я делаю стартер где использются эти пакеты + удобная возможность переключаться между ssr и spa: https://github.com/iliyaZelenko/laravel-nuxt